# Angular Material set mat-checkbox checked programatically

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

I am doing an Angular 12 Material APP.. I have a list of checked created dynamically like this

```
   <li *ngFor="let channel of dataSourceChannelLevel">
            <mat-checkbox id={{channel.NotificationLogLevel.Id}} formControlName="Channel"
             (change)="onChangeEventFunc( $event)">
              {{channel.NotificationLogLevel.Name}}
            </mat-checkbox>
 </li>
```

I want also to checked them depending on the condition of

```
 "channel.NotificationLogLevel.IsActive"
```

I have tried with

```
 value= "channel.NotificationLogLevel.IsActive"
```

but those not work...

Also with

```
 [checked] = "channel.NotificationLogLevel.IsActive"
```

Also I tested calling a function...

```
[checked]= "CheckMe()"
```

and in the component

```
CheckMe()
{
    console.log("here");
     return true;
}
```

It logs "Here" but the combo is not checked...

The only things it works is `[ngModel]` but it checked all the mat-checkbox where checked or unchecked.

I can not set them from Html nor Component.

I am using Material API `MatCheckboxModule`.

Is another API I am missing? Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is just a syntax error, you probably want to do =>

```
[checked]="chanel.NotificationLogLevel.IsActive"
```

Mapped attributes inside brackets "[]" are interpreted directly.

Comment: Thanks, but still does not work...

Comment: Have you checked that `chanel.NotificationLogLevel.IsActive` in that particular iteration is set to true? Millenion answer is correct.

Comment: I add more details, it seems that nothing works.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem...

When I defined the FormGroup I add defined

```
Channel: new FormControl(''),
```

insted of

```
Channel: new FormArray([])
```

And in the HTML I had defined

```
 <mat-checkbox id= {{chanel.NotificationLogLevel.Name}} formGroupName="Channel"
```

instead of

```
 <mat-checkbox id= {{chanel.NotificationLogLevel.Name}} formArrayName="Channel"
```